# Angular: Why doesn't CSS justification work with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to evenly space the `li` in a `ul` (justify). The CSS works when I hardcode the `li`, but when I use `ng-repeat`, the CSS is no longer applied.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="SampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
        <ul class="two-column">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="two-column">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.two-column {
    text-align: justify;
}

.two-column:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;   
}
```

**The fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/RyanWalters/M8228/

**Expected result**

Both lists should have space between each `li`.

**Actual result**

The list generated with `ng-repeat` has no space between each `li`.

**Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whitespace between the `li` elements (necessary for the justification) is not emitted with Angular's repetition.  You also have to wrap the whitespace so it gets repeated.  You can do something like:

```
<span ng-repeat-start="item in items"></span>
    <li></li>
<span ng-repeat-end></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M8228/1/

Comment: @Populus I tend to agree.  Ideally there would be a comment version of the repeat directive like Knockout allows you to do, but such is not the case in Angular

Comment: or you need to rethink why you even need to justify a bunch of `inline-block` in the first place. If you have a fixed number of items, the items should be fixed in width; if the number can vary, using justified gives you inconsistent results which is bad for UX.

Comment: @Populus: You are right that this is bad for UX. I had this exact same problem, and when I finally got it to work, it looked strange.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
<ul class="two-column" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
```

and float the `li` elements?

css:

```
.two-column {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}



.two-column li {
    background-color: #f00;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: You obviously don't know what justify does. It is for spreading items evenly througout the full width of the container. Originally it is intended for having text that is justified inside a paragraph so that the words on the left align perfectly, and the words are spread out with correct space between so the the words also aligns perfectly on the right side. This can also be used on boxes by using `display:inline-block` which basically say that the box behaves as a "text element" so that you can use text flow techniques to handle the layout.